# CSS: Start numbering pages with 2 instead of 1

Tags: css, counter

In CSS, with:

```
@page { @top-right { content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages); } }
```

I can have page numbers displayed at the top of every page when the page is printed. This works great. But now, how can I make it so the page number starts with 2 instead of 1? Can I do that by modifying the CSS rule above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Flying Saucer (which was my case), use the following CSS:

> table { -fs-table-paginate: paginate; }

It works like a charm. And Flying Saucer rocks :). Really highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
@page {
    counter-increment: page;
    counter-reset: page 1;
    @top-right {
        content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
    }
}
```

using `page 1` will reset the starting point of the counter. You can use any integer to start counting from. The default is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

After playing with Flying Saucer a bit, I guess there's no way to do this with CSS (or it's a very complicated one), as "page"/"pages" seem to be internal CSS variables. Perhaps it gets better with CSS 3, there seems to be a calc() function, so counter(calc(page+1)) could *perhaps* work...

But there is another way to get the PDF starting with page 2. You can add a blank first page to the PDF by adding this line to the xhtml file:

```
<h1 style="page-break-before:always"></h1>
```

Then you can either print only pages 2-... of the PDF when using a printer or remove the first page from the PDF with some PDF editor.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the CSS documentation about counters? [see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters) It seems to me that you can call the counter-reset. By default counters are set to 0. If in your Body tag you did a "content-reset: page 1;" then it should force the first page to start at 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for someone else viewing this page.  You can also look into another stackoverflow post provided below.  This has worked for me.

[flying saucer - page count with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136505/flying-saucer-page-count-with-css)

```
.seq-start{
    -fs-page-sequence: start;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't know if this works, but why don't you try `counter(page+1)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I am using Flying Saucer (https://xhtmlrenderer.dev.java.net/).