# flying saucer - page count with css

Tags: java, css, pdf, flying-saucer

I'm using flying saucer to convert HTML data to PDF, but I've one issue to solve.

- In my PDF the first page is a introductory page, so this page don't have a number.
- The second page must have a number, and the number of page two must be 1. The thrid page must show Page 2 and etc.

I want the page counter to only begin on the second page.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered. Just put "-fs-page-sequence" in a style on page that you want to start the counter, and the page counter will be reseted.

For instance:

```
<div style='-fs-page-sequence'></div>
```

> -fs-page-sequence: values start or auto (the default) and allows you to limit the scope of the page and pages counters to a portion of the
>   document

Comment: If anyone comes here trying to figure out how to do this, the code in the accepted answer is incomplete.

It should be ```<div style="-fs-page-sequence: start"></div> ```